# Rename factors from list (in R)

Tags: r, rename

## My Data

The data are from a large survey in a set of developing countries. The data include, among other things, variables on each respondent's country and local region (within the country).

The only problem is that, instead of coding **local region** as strings (such as "New York" or "Westchester County", it is coded as numeric, which correspond to a list of regions in the codebook.

## My Question

What I would like to know is whether there's a way to automate the process of re-naming the factors using the codelist from the codebook. Each region is preceded by a numeric value and an equals sign, and is followed immediately by a comma.

This list takes this form:

```
1=New York, 2=Paris, 3=London, 4=Moscow, 5=Boston, ..., 230=Tblisi
```

Is there some R code that might allow me to quickly rename all the factors in this variable using this list?

Comment: Does your "list" just exist in a text file? Or is it an R object?

Comment: Hi @jbaums, thank you for your feedback. I wanted to be sure to provide enough information to give context to the question. To answer your question, the list exists in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a text file with a vector like

```
 1=New York, 2=Paris, 3=London, 4=Moscow, 5=Boston, ..., 230=Tblisi
```

you're going to have to do some regex to extract the cities from the numbers. For example, you could do:

```
 library(stringr)
 List <- c("1=New York", "2=Paris", "3=London", "4=Moscow", "5=Boston")
 Cities <- data.frame(Orig = List)
 Cities$CityNum <- str_extract(Cities$Orig, "[0-9]{1,}") # match the number at least once
 Cities$City <- str_sub(Cities$Orig, 
                   start = str_locate(Cities$Orig, "[A-Z]")[, 1],
                   end = str_length(Cities$Orig))
```

Assuming that you have a column in MyData called "CityNum" that lists the number...

```
 MyData <- merge(MyData, Cities, by = CityNum)
```

And I must agree with jbaums about being concise. :-)

Comment: Dear @LauraS, thank you for your response. The list is in the form that I specified in the original post. I am hoping to scrape the data without retyping every value or manually adding quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strsplit` on the codelist and then use the result as the levels and labels for your factor.

```
citylist <- c("1=New York", "2=Paris", "3=London", "4=Moscow", "5=Boston")
codes <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(citylist, "="))) # Split and bind the result into a dataframe

set.seed(85)
mycities <- ceiling(runif(10, 0, 5))     # Generate some dummy data
mycities <- factor(mycities, levels = codes$X1, labels = codes$X2)
```

Which gives:

```
[1] London   New York Paris    Moscow   London   Boston   New York New York New York
[10] Boston  
Levels: New York Paris London Moscow Boston
```

Comment: Hi @Jay, thank you very much for your feedback. I will try that now.